# How to take a string and return the capitalized format of a word

Tags: java, string, capitalize

```
int length = s.length();

if (length = 0){
    return s;
}

else {
    return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ s.substring(1);
}
```

I get two errors saying:

```
if (length = 0){
^^^^^^^^^^
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean


return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ s.substring(1);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Cannot invoke toUpperCase() on the primitive type char
```

Plus, if it's an empty sting it should just return it.
That's why I'm using an If-Else statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (length = 0)` should be `if (length == 0)`

You're assigning the value 0 to `length` and not *comparing* it to 0.

I recommend you to take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26):

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of
>   the variable after the assignment has occurred. The result of an
>   assignment expression is not itself a variable.

This way, your `if` is never satisfied since the value inside it evaluated to the value of the assigned (0 in this case), so your program goes to the `else`, and there you should:

```
return Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1);
```

Comment: Perfectly explained! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `if` statement, you are assigning the value `0` to `length`.  Because of this your compiler is complaining, because it expects a `boolean` expression, and not an int in the `if` statement (assignment returns the value it is assigning, which is why it mentions the `int`).

You mean to be evaluating a boolean expression by using `==` instead.

The second issue is because `charAt(int)` returns a `char` primitive, which doesn't have any methods.

In this case you probably want to utilize `Character.toUpperCase(char)` on the first character of your `String` and appending the rest.

Answer (score 2):

you're missing the `==` in the if statement

`charAt(0)` returns a char, one way to make this a string is `Character.toString(c)`

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
if (length == 0) {
    return s;
}

return Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1);
```

Note: if the length of the string is exactly 1, you'll still get an error, because of `s.substring(1)`. You might want to add an additional condition for when the length of the string is exactly 1.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if (length = 0) {
```

means "*I want to set the length to zero*". But what you want is

```
if (length == 0) {
```

which means "*Is the length equal to zero?*"

The first statement eventually results into an exception as you're passing an integer into a place where boolean is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
String s = "testing";
String upper = s.toUpperCase();
System.out.print(upper);
```